# Smooth Bootstrap Column Drop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there an easy way to make a smooth column drop in Bootstrap?

A really nice example is shown here, when you downsize your browser-window.

> https://www.emirates.com/de/german/

You can see, that the boxes, placed in the middle of the page, move smooth from 2er Grid to 1er Grid.

Best Chris :)

Comment: Remember that questions should be helpful to future readers. Please post the relevant code in the question instead of linking to external sites that may change over time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I believe you're looking for the col classes.

Assigning the col-12, col-md-8, and col-lg-6 classes to an element will make it take up half the display (6 columns) with a large display or window, 8 columns on a medium-sized display, and 12 on everything else.

Here's an in-depth look on Quackit. https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/tutorial/bootstrap_grid_system.cfm

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I know the bootstrap col-classes. But i'd like smooth col drops not such hard break points :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "smooth." Are you looking for the -fluid classes? That would make your columns continue to take up the whole width of the page as they're resized.